# Rails 3 - adding inputs with values (nested-form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have some troubles with Rails3 and nested-form gem.

Adding empty inputs is great but I also want to have select tag with predefined filled forms, and when I choose one of options script will add inputs with defined value to my form.

How can I add input fields with values to nested form?

Comment: jason328: I tried to invoke adding empty fields and then to change value, but I had problems with selecting inputs.

Comment: Can you show us some sample code? What was the exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think nested form just add some methods to form builder, so you do it through standard helpers:

```
- f.fields_for :nested_model do |nested_builder|
  = nested_builder.select :method, Model.all.collect {|m| [ m.name, m.id ] }, { :include_blank => true }
```

Comment: Ok, I have document with 2 entries in databse - that means 2 nested forms. I can have access to it by javascript: `$('#document_products_attributes_1_price')` but the problem is when I add new field and do not save (data only in browser).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have just solved it. The solution is to add class name to field like this:
`<td><%= tf.text_field :name, :class=>'f_name' %></td>`
Then we invoke form adding function and to change value we use
`$('.f_name:last')`

Anyway, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

The nested_form gem triggers a javascript event when a nested form is added. There's [an example in the README](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form#jquery) that initializes a datepicker:

```
$(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){
  // this field was just inserted into your form
  var field = event.field; 
  // it's a jQuery object already! Now you can find date input
  var dateField = field.find('.date');
  // and activate datepicker on it
  dateField.datepicker();
})
```